# Are there any MacBook permissions that would allow/block an iPad app (running on a MacBook) to use the clipboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, ios-appstore, apple-silicon, copy-paste

I am using Ventura 13.3.1 M1 MacBook Pro.

I have an iPad app (FortiToken Mobile v5.4.3 ) running on this MacBook. I would like to copy-paste text from this app to the MacBook’s clipboard. This used to work before, but after a recent update (in the last 6 months) the "Copy" context menu item is now disabled.

I haven't updated the app since. Does the app now need some special "Privacy and Security" permission in order to access the clipboard?

Comment: What's the app and what's its version? How do you exactly try to select text to be copy-pasted and then the said context menu, i.e. using the mouse to select the text and then right-clicking with the mouse on the selected text?

Comment: The app is FortiToken Mobile v5.4.3 and the context menu appears when I long-click in the app.

Comment: Thx. By a long-click, do you mean a long left-click or right-click? Does the text you need get automatically selected when you long-click or do you select the text (and how) prior to the long-click?

Comment: does it work in other apps?

Comment: TBH, it may just be poor implementation on the app, or a bug. Is the Edit menu not available? Can you select the text? Perhaps the app doesn't want you to copy the on-time token, for security reasons?  It's worth asking the developers. Just to correct some understanding: the app is running on your MacBook Pro -- you copy to the clipboard, which is available to any other application, also running on the MacBook Pro. You don't copy "to the MBP".

Comment: @Alper Long "touchpad-click", regardless of the position on the touchpad. No next gets highlighted, just the disabled "Copy" context-menu item appears. Clicking on it has no effect. Just pressing ESC cancels it.

Comment: @benwiggy I tend to agree with the "poor" part. And there is the Edit menu of the app with all the text operations disabled (up to the "Spelling and Grammar" section).

Comment: Rephrased the title question to match the body question.

Comment: It's up to the app itself to support clipboard. The OS can't 'force' an app to add a feature.